# The problem when installing mongodb on MacOS

Tags: mongodb

I tried to install mongodb on my Mac. But the error message below appeared.
Someone please tell me the solution.

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Installing mongodb-community from mongodb/brew
==> Downloading https://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.4.1.tgz
Already downloaded: /Users/t17akeru/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/d46781539dca95a7ced7d9b466b13bd4cc0202f17a8bf4bd499a5e1a4a241262--mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.4.1.tgz
Error: Failed to install plist file
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall mongodb/brew/mongodb-community`
==> Caveats
To have launchd start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community now and restart at login:
  brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/4.4.1: 11 files, 136.8MB, built in 4 seconds
==> `brew cleanup` has not been run in 30 days, running now...
Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/share/5.2/luarocks/add.lua
```

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB was correctly installed. The problem is the installation of the plist file (which allows you to launch MongoDB when your computer starts, for example).
You can still run MongDB using `mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`.

Also, brew seems to have some permission problem. Here are some possible resolutions from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/45009):

### Reinstalling Brew

```sh
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

### Resetting permissions in /usr/local

```sh
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/* \
&& sudo chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local/*
```

You can then try to run MongoDB's post-install script using `brew postinstall mongodb/brew/mongodb-community`

Hope it helped !

Comment: thank you for replying. but i could not do even "mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf"

Error opening config file: Is a directory
try 'mongod --help' for more information